# SQL server agent SSIS error

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssis

I get the following error when I execute my package as a SQL server agent job.

It is an SSIS 2008 package running on a SQL Server 2008 instance. My package security is DontSaveSensitive.

I don't even know how to begin fixing this error.

Where should I check first?

```
Date        a value of time
Log     Job History (MyJob)

Step ID     1
Server      PCTSQL004
Job Name        MyJob
Step Name       Job_1
Duration        00:00:00
Sql Severity        0
Sql Message ID      0
Operator Emailed        
Operator Net sent       
Operator Paged      
Retries Attempted       0

Message
Executed as user: CS\DmcSysManager. The process could not be created for step 1 of job 0x63BB5A86DB23F947866D2A806BE4CC6B (reason: A required privilege is not held by the client).  The step failed.
```

Comment: --> "A required privilege is not held by the client" Without seeing the package definition, it could be quite a few things.

Comment: @MitchWheat - how can I give you that information ? Please tell me and i will get it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to [SQL.Net Warrior's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17206715/57611) there is another option:

1. Add a new Credential in SSMS (under Security) and enter a domain or local user that has the privileges needed by the package, plus the password for this user. This will be in the form `DOMAIN\USER` or `SYSTEMNAME\USER`.
2. Under SQL Server Agent -> Proxies, add a new Proxy. Check the subsystem "SQL Server Integration Services Package", and enter the name of the Credential you created in step 1.
3. Now in the step of your job that runs the SSIS package, there will be a new entry in the "Run As" dropdown with the name of the Proxy you created.
4. Select the Proxy, save, and your job step will now run as the user, and succeed!

Note that in the Credential setup, there is an option to select an Encryption Provider (which itself appears to need some special installation/setup). I have not researched this to understand it fully, but I suspect it is to securely store the password. You should research this for yourself and understand it before proceeding with this method--just to understand any potential security concerns around the password.

Answer (score 2):

As a general guideline, the account that runs the package as a job step must have all the same permissions as an account that runs the package directly, in order to access any external resources that the package needs to access.

If the package is stored in the MSDB database, and you've set the protection level to Rely on server storage and roles for access control, the Database roles now control read and write access to the package.

You need to assign one of the Integration Services fixed database-level roles or assign a user-defined database-level role, to the Reader role of the package. The fixed database-level roles in SQL Server 2008 are db_ssisadmin, db_ssisoperator, and db_ssisltduser.

If you assign a fixed database-level role to the package, the user account that calls the package from the job step must be a member of that role. If you assign a user-defined role to the package, the user account must be a member of one of the fixed database-level roles and a member of the user-defined role. 
Also check [Permissions Issue running SSIS package from Sql Job](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10489392/permissions-issue-running-ssis-package-from-sql-job)

**Alternatively, you can**

I did face the same problem and my problem was solved with the following steps -

1. Add SQL Server Service account at SQLServer2005MSSQLUser$ComputerName$MSSQLSERVER windows Group
2. Add SQL Server Service account at  SQLServer2005SQLAgentUser$ComputerName$MSSQLSERVER windows Group
3. Restart your server