# SSIS Get Image from Shared Folder

Tags: ssis, sql-server-2008-r2

I have this DTSX Package in SSIS for copying images from shared folder.

[image: DTSX Package]

The Get Image Path is connecting to database to get the shared folder path (Im using credentials when accessing this path from explorer),
the Foreach Loop container get the images from the image path that is returned by the previous task and while looping the file system task saves the images to my image folder.

When I run this on BIDS, its working. (I used NET USE on DOS command to access the folder with a specific credentials)

Can I add credentials to DTSX Package (specifically to Foreach Loop Container) for this to run on SQL Server Job?

Thanks.

Comment: Something similar has been asked elsewhere on [StackOverflow][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10489392/permissions-issue-running-ssis-package-from-sql-job

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SQL server ManagementStudio, go to security -> credentials. Then add a new Credential for a user that has the read/write permissions to the folder. After the credential is added, you can go into the SQL Server agent job, right click then properties then edit the job step. Then in the "run as"drop down, select your credential.